# How to export revision on commit with a post-commit hook?

Tags: svn, powershell, hook, visualsvn-server, post-commit

It may be handy to export the specific Subversion repository branch after a commit, using a post-commit hook.

E.g. to **update a website after a commit** or to update a development branch for testing.

Is there any instruction or sample of such a hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice for writing a hook script for Subversion in Windows environment (e.g. [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)) is to use [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell) scripting language or good ol' [Windows batch command-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_batch_file).

Here is the sample code of *post-commit.bat* and *post-commit.ps1* that should be used together to export a committed revision to `C:\Test`. Put them into your repository 'hooks' folder, e.g. `C:\Repositories\repository\hooks\`

***post-commit.ps1***

```
# Store hook arguments into variables with mnemonic names
$repos = $args[0]
$rev   = $args[1]

# Build path to svn.exe
$svn = "$env:VISUALSVN_SERVER\bin\svn.exe"

# Build url to repository
$urepos = $repos -replace "\\", "/"
$url = "file:///$urepos/"

# Export repository revision $rev to the C:\test folder
&"$svn" export -r $rev --force "$url" c:\test
```

***post-commit.bat***

```
@echo off

set PWSH=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%PWSH% -command $input ^| %1\hooks\post-commit.ps1 %1 %2  
if errorlevel 1 exit %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Is their any way to update only the changed files?
I added the question here please check. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23670606/1357033

Comment: @bahrep Is there a way to add the repository name to the export path. example:  c:\test\$urepos   ?

Comment: @DavidKEgghead you can parse `$repos` to get the name of the repository.